# Solr : Unexpected result

Tags: solr

I am using highlighting feature of solr. Well its doing great except one thing. Here is the problem in response

```
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">9</int>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" maxScore="0.6901834">
  <doc>
    <str name="desc">I study in school</str>
    <str name="name">school</str>
    <str name="value">DPS</str>
    <str name="country">India</str>
    <str name="state">delhi</str>
    <str name="city">New Delhi</str>
    <str name="area">R.K. Puram</str>
    <str name="id">c02101a4-c5c2-46a9-bb73-805208167b3c</str>
    <float name="score">0.6901834</float></doc>
</result>
<lst name="highlighting">
  <lst name="c02101a4-c5c2-46a9-bb73-805208167b3c">
    <arr name="name">
      <str>school</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="value">
      <str><em>DP</em>S</str>
    </arr>
  </lst>
 </lst>
</response>
```

In highlighting section , Why am I getting "name":"school" field ??? Even though it is not getting highlighted like "value":"DPS" ..

Thanks

Comment: whats your query ? what are your configuration ??

Comment: My Query is 'DPS'  and i am boosting 'value'^14 , area^12 , city^10 , state^8 , country^6 , desc^4 , name^2

Comment: whats the field type for name field ?? are you using any synonyms ? what are the highlighting configuration ?